# mysql:ERROR 1064 (42000) in trigger

Tags: mysql, error-handling, triggers

This is a trigger i write.

```
DELIMITER //
create trigger after_insert_bid
after insert on Bid
for each row
when exists(
    select * 
    from Item
    where ItemID = new.ItemID)
begin
update Item set Item.currently = NEW.amount where Item.itemID = NEW.itemID;
end;//
DELIMITER ;
```

It has an error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'when exists(
SELECT *
FROM Item
WHERE ItemID = new.ItemID
)
begin
UPDATE Item SE' at line 4
mysql> end;
```

I am new to mysql, and i know it's an simple question, but i really don't know how to find the error, thank you!

mysql version is 5.1.73

Comment: You found the error. Did you check the syntax versus what's specified in the manual?

Comment: my version is mysql 5.1.73. I tried found it in the manual, but it didn't work.sorry

Comment: You can't do a `WHEN EXISTS` there, so you need a different approach. Look at what *trigger_event* types there are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check whether the itemid exists in item table just update the item table directly. The table will not be updated if ItemID do not exists in Item table.

```
for each row 
begin
  update Item set Item.currently = NEW.amount where Item.itemID = NEW.itemID;
end
```